# Android set TextView to instance of nested class

Tags: android, android-xml, typeface

I am currently in the process of overhauling the font of my application to use a custom font.

I have a class such as this:

```
public class TextViewRobotoRegular extends TextView {

    public TextViewRobotoRegular(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            setTypeface(Typefaces.get(context, "Roboto-BlackItalic"));           
        }
    }
}
```

where `Typefaces.get` is a method which points to a cached typeface, and if not cached, creates a new instance.

For organization sake, I was wondering if I could make several TextView classes for each font within one large class, something like this

```
public class TextViews {

    public class RobotoRegular extends TextView {

        public TextViewRobotoRegular(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            if (!isInEditMode()) {
                setTypeface(Typefaces.get(context, "Roboto-Thin"));           
            }
        }
    }

    public class RobotoThin extends TextView {

        public TextViewRobotoRegular(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            if (!isInEditMode()) {
                setTypeface(Typefaces.get(context, "Roboto-Thin"));           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can I make these references in the xml layout files? something like:

```
<com.example.appname.fontPackageName.TextViews.RobotoRegular
    android:id="@+id/profileNameView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make classes RobotoRegular and RobotoThin **public static**.

And edit xml like this:

```
    <view class="com.example.appname.fontPackageName.TextViews$RobotoRegular"
    android:id="@+id/profileNameView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: And reference them how from within the xml file?

Comment: The '$' is an illegal character within the xml file

Comment: Have you tested it yourself and can confirm it to be working? I keep experiencing class cast exceptions and am thinking I must be referencing the name incorrectly or something

Comment: Did you make nested classes public static?

Comment: Yep! I made the nested class `RobotoRegular` static and reference it like in your code shown.

Comment: If you use Eclipse, try to clean project. Hope this helps.